# Regular expression to match C++-wide string literals (L"...")

Tags: c++, regex, string-literals

I'm looking for a regular expression to match wide string literals in C++ source code, i.e. those starting with a capital `L`:

```
L"Hello World!"
```

There may be several literals on a line, and it must not match `L", "` in the following example:

```
"some string literal ending in L", "another string literal"
```

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Unless you're parsing C++ itself, this question doesn't make sense. A wide-character literal is not something you "match", because you can't have a wide-character literal within a narrow string. Strings in C++ are either narrow, wide, UTF-16, or UTF-32. They can't be part one and part the other.

Comment: @NicolBolas Sorry, I thought it was obvious that I'm talking about applying this regex to files containing C++ source code.

Comment: That can't be your problem, it seems more like the solution you have in mind isn't working out for you.

Comment: To do this with regex "correctly" you should match all quoting constructs (strings, comments, escapes, etc), and only do what you want with the ones you want. What language and regex flavor do you have in mind for doing these matches?

Comment: @Qtax Whatever Sublime 2 supports ;) I want to do regex search and replace, so if there's a better editor/tool available, I'd also be willing to try that.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression partially solves the problem by matching the last `L`-string literal (and everything before):

```
(^[^"\r\n]*(?:"[^"\r\n]*"[^"\r\n]*)*)L"([^"\r\n]*)"
```

This allowed me to repeatedly search and replace regex with this replacement:

```
\1u"\2"
```

which was good enough for my task (replacing `L`-literals with `u`-literals).